# Encoding mismatch in connection and Python

Tags: character-encoding, python-3.6, firebird

I am having some troubles getting my Firebird connection to work, and it all seems related to encodings. I am connecting to the database like this (`local_copy` is `/path/to/database.fdb`):

```
conn = fdb.connect(dsn=local_copy, user='****', password='****', charset="ISO8859_1")
```

which only works for certain charsets. I need to have the `ISO8859_1` charset, which worked before, but not anymore (perhaps because of an update).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sync.py", line 10, in <module>
    conn = fdb.connect(dsn=local_copy, user='**', password='**', charset="ISO8859_1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 848, in connect
    "Error while connecting to database:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -924\n- bad parameters on attach or create database\n- CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 is not defined', -924, 335544325)
```

When I use `ISO88591`, the connect works, but Python is not happy with that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sync.py", line 10, in <module>
    conn = fdb.connect(dsn=local_copy, user='***', password='***', charset="ANSI")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 826, in connect
    no_reserve, db_key_scope, no_gc, no_db_triggers, no_linger)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 759, in build_dpb
    dpb.add_string_parameter(isc_dpb_user_name, user)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 624, in add_string_parameter
    value = value.encode(charset_map.get(self.charset, self.charset))
LookupError: unknown encoding: ISO88591
```

So, I thought perhaps adding an alias `ISO88591` to Python would work. I tried to edit the `/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/aliases.py`, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: why not using UTF-8 encoding? it seems to practically be a universal superset of all other encodings ?

Comment: @Arioch'The because the database is created by another application. And they use ISO8859-1. And ISO8859-1 is not a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: does connecting as UTF-8 really cause any detrimental effects or is it a non-tested superstition?

Comment: @Arioch'The using UTF-8 does not work. It will give an encoding problem when fetching data. I tried.

Comment: You may try "NONE" charset - but I do not know if Python would support it. Then the textual data should be transferred as raw binary dump to the application, leaving all charset-related transcoding to Python. Dunno if it would work... I am really surprised by the claim that ISO8859-1 has letters that are missed from the Unicode even today

Comment: @Arioch'The `NONE` falls back to UTF-8 and Python will try to decode the data as UTF-8 and fail: `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 9: invalid start byte`.

Comment: This would indicate that the database may store ISO-8859-1 characters, but its columns are declared as character set NONE, otherwise Firebird would automatically transliterate between character sets.

Comment: This table - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 - shows that except for 65 "undefined" character all other characters ARE subset of Unicode. In particular, `ü 00FC` Unicode is exactly what is 0xFC in ISO8859-1. Wikipedia also have an interesting comment that may be can be used by you: `For the character encoding commonly mislabeled as "ISO-8859-1", see Windows-1252.` - Try the latter.

Comment: This was my 3rd comment, before "NONE" suggestion, that I previously deleted: That is important information, missed in the question... Basically that can happen when text is stored as raw binary data. Either when creating tables or columns they explicitly set their charset to 'NONE' or they were creating it with connection charset set to 'NONE' and it was implicitly borrowed... Basically it seems you have a database, where DECLARATION of some columns in the tables contradicts their real data. This is dangerous situation and the proper way would be fixing the DB and application saving that data

Comment: Note though that your assertion that _"When I use ISO88591, the connect work"_ is not correct, the traceback happens inside the connect, before it connects to Firebird

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that depends upon what we mean by "connect". For me it looks like the very connect to the database happens, then after the Firebird connect, but before exiting Python connect, FDB module makes seom extra work, some bootstrapping, and fails there.

Comment: Could you please post the value of `local_copy` (or if you need to anonymize it, make sure it reflects the same structure).

Comment: @Arioch'The The traceback indicates it happens when fdb is constructing the DPB to send to Firebird, so although it may have initiated the handshake (I didn't dive in the code), this happens at least **before** attach (as you need the DPB for the attach).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel then where it gets SQLCODE = -924 if not from fbclient.dll ? // I really am confused by "most recent call last" - is the last call topmost or bottommost? was call sequence top to bottom or bottom to top?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `local_copy` is a defined as `/path/to/database.fdb`. And it can work without supplying the `charset` parameter and connecting as UTF-8, as long as I do not `SELECT` any data that cannot be UTF-8-decoded.

Comment: You are right about the `ISO88591` thing. I have been sitting with this issue for a few days now, trying many many things....

Comment: What happens if you use an actual Firebird server and connect through localhost:/path/to/database.fdb instead?

Comment: again, try windows codepages 1250 and 1252 - while they are NOT exactly 8859-1, one often can get away with them for most of characters

Comment: @Arioch'The The error indicates that character support is broken somehow, if ISO8859_1 doesn't exist, it is unlikely that win1252 does exist.

Comment: In particular I am VERY confused with "ANSI" in the trace `File "sync.py", line 10, in <module>
    conn = fdb.connect(dsn=local_copy, user='***', password='***', charset="ANSI")` while Bart says he used ISO-something. Does it mean, Python stack tracebacks are unreliable w.r.t. parameter values?

Comment: Does `select * from rdb$character_sets where rdb$character_set_name = 'ISO8859_1'` actually return a row?

Comment: I think I'll repeat my comment on your previous (now deleted) question on this subject: it might be better to post this to firebird-support instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes. I tried connecting using `isql-fb` and it works, but when adding `-charset ISO8859_1` I get the same error.

Comment: I'd like to see the exact declaration, including charsets/collations, of the table/column that data gives Bart trouble. Is it `NONE` or ISO-something or something else? I think free tools like FlameRobin can show it? Or IBExpert Personal on Windows? Otherwise one would have to make join-selects over at least 4 system tables https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-appx04-systables.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I did post to the Firebird support group as well ... Without any result, as off-topic this might be here, I still get *some* results... As said, this is costing me a lot of time already.

Comment: there is one more test perhaps. To make the copy of that database to another file in the original server ( I remind - it would take either temporarily stopping FB server process there, or using backup/restore facilities for copying ). Then Bart can use his Python program to connect new database copy on the old server. He claims, some "old program" does connect to that server using ISO-charset. That should mean the FB server installed on the old server does not have charsets issue.

Comment: Then such a connection test would make it clear whether the issue is in incomplete (charsets-less) FB Server on Bart's machine, or if something is wrong in Python.

Comment: Does Firebird accept any of the Python aliases for this character set? Python calls it `latin_1` with aliases `iso-8859-1`, `iso8859-1`, `8859`, `cp819`, `latin`, `latin1`, and `L1`.

Comment: I intentionally didn't reply yet on firebird-support, to see if someone else has a better idea. I'm not that well-versed on Linux installs, however the problem you have is easy to reproduce on Windows by breaking its character support (by making the `intl\fbintl.dll`  of the Firebird install inaccessible). This suggests it is also the problem on your system.

Comment: (Oh that's from old Python documentation; the current canonical label is `iso-8859-1`.)

Comment: @tripleee That won't help, because the actual problem is that it will need to map to ISO8859_1 on Firebird, which doesn't seem to properly work on Barts Firebird install.

Comment: @tripleee no. I only had success with `UTF8` and `ASCII`.

Comment: ASCII and UTF8 work because they aren't defined using fbintl.dll (or libfbintl.so).

Comment: Bart, based on the current information I can only conclude that something is really broken with your Firebird install. Consider trying to reinstall.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have removed and re-installed everything (twice). But perhaps three times is the charm ... Thanks a lot all.

Comment: I have replied to your mail on the firebird-support list for more information, because I don't think this wall of comments is going to get us anywhere.

Comment: @BartFriederichs make a copy of the database on the ORIGINAL server (so you would not mess with production database) and try to connect there - if it will go, then it is ok  with Python and your app and thing is about Firebird distro on your OS. Alternatively, get urself some VirtualBox or something, install WinXP there, install FB server into XP by official exe install, copy database file onto virtual XP  and try connecting with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short summary of what was posted on Firebird-support, it looks the `fbintl` module in Firebird 2.5.8 on CentOS is broken.

As indicated by Philippe Makowski:

> Sorry, it is broken, and I don't know how to fix it :
>   https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1636177
>
> but Firebird 3 is ok
>   https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/makowski/firebird/

A possible workaround suggested in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1636177 is to either downgrade to 2.5.7, or to continue using 2.5.8, but replace its `fbintl` module with the one from 2.5.7.